# Are players listed by Elo on normal?

Tags: league-of-legends

In Ranked game, it is my understanding that players are listed by Elo, with the highest Elo being the team captain and the lowest Elo being the last pick.

Is the same logic applied to normal games? If I'm listed as fifth on my team, does that mean I have the lowest normal Elo score on my team or is there no particular order in normal games?

Comment: You can find out yourself with a simple experiment; party up with a friend who you know it win/loss ratio is considerable greater or lower than yours and get yourselves into a normal match.

Comment: @camiloqp Unfortunately, win/loss ratio isn't an accurate indicator of ELO.

Comment: I know, but it does account largely when there are big differences between W/L ratio of 2 players. Just think of how Ranked ELO works in the very broad sense ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there any ranking in normal mode. You have your level plus number of win/loss. 
If order there is, it's definitely not a ELO score. (For normal game I mean)

#### Edit

I found this that may invalidate what I said:

> The results of normal games count towards the Summoner's Win / Lose / Leaves score. Additionally, your ELO is changed according to the result, you earn points if you win and lose some if you lose. The number of ELO-points you gain or lose is calculated by an unknown formula, taking the expected result due to the ELO-values of all participants into consideration.

Source from : http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Normal_game

Comment: I know there used to be a normal ELO; you could find it if you went through the log files, but you can't find it there anymore. I don't know why they'd remove normal ELO entirely though, so I suppose it's still there.

Comment: No. there IS a normal Elo. That I'm 100% sure. Reds on the forums make many references to it, and it's clear that they use it for matchmaking. Example: http://www.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=9577154

Comment: There *is* an ELO - it's what's used in matchmaking. The difference between Normal and Ranked games is that ELO is hidden in Normal

Answer (score 1):

There is no ranking on normal, but they DO use ELO for normal games!!! It's only hidden and not visible to players. It used to be findable on lolbase.net, but that hasn't been working for a while now (since Augustus 2010).

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no ranking?"

Comment: Your not ranked on a listing or anything. There is no #1 in normal games. Although your not ranked, you do get higher ELO for winning a game in normal, and you do lose points in your normal ELO for losing

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a normal premade draft mode game, then the team captain is actually based on alphabetical order of summoner name.  However, if you are doing a blind pick game in normal, order means absolutely nothing.

As other have mentioned, there is an ELO for normal games as well.  It is the same ELO number for both draft mode and blind pick.  It is the same for all game modes, except maybe dominion which has a different ELO rating.  No you cannot see your normal ELO number yourself, you can at best guesstimate it based on your W/L ratio/difference.  There is an actual max ELO rating you can get in Normal, so there is an upper bound limit for it.